# Using jQuery to get descdent nodes in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Could someone tell me what the jQuery equivalent of this would be?

```
var shapes=document.getElementsByTagName("shapes")[0];
thisCircle=shapes.getElementsByTagName("circle")[index];
```

Comment: `$("shapes:first circle")[index]` as long as the browser recognizes `shapes` and `circle` as valid elements.

Comment: That's what I tried initially except I left the ":first " out.  Hence I had the wrong syntax.  Thanks, Peter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it. Here's how I'd write it:

```
$('shapes').first().find('circle').eq(index)
```

Comment: Indeed it does!  Thank you very much!  I will accept the answer when the waiting period is up.

Comment: It is sometimes more efficient to just put multiple specifications into the selector rather than call multiple methods.  Both will work fine, but I prefer to let the CSS selector syntax do more of the work if possible and these allows the selector engine more of a chance to optimize the operation.  Note that this code creates four separate jQuery objects.

Comment: @jfriend00: jQuery tries to use `getElementById` and similar functions before resorting to `querySelectorAll` and its own DOM traversal methods (which is used here due to `:first`), so the methods with simple selectors are usually faster: http://jsperf.com/selector-string-vs-methods

Comment: @Blender - wow, `querySelectorAll()` must really suck for two extra method calls and two extra intermediate jQuery objects to be faster.

Comment: @jfriend00: It is much faster if it's actually used.

Comment: @Blender - Ahh, `:first` is not native CSS so `querySelectorAll()` can't even be used.  Never mind.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the tags directly in the CSS selector and use modifiers like `:first` to let the CSS selector engine do most of the work for you and to create the fewest intermediate jQuery objects.

`.eq(index)` selects the `index` item from all the items found and returns a jQuery object.  Directly indexing it with array syntax like `[index]` will return a DOM object (not a jQuery object):

```
$("shapes:first circle").eq(index)
```

The step by step description of what is going on here is this:

1. Find the first shapes object.
2. Find all circle objects that are descendants of that first shape object and construct a jQuery object that contains all those circle objects.
3. Call the `eq()` method on the jQuery object to make a new jQuery object that contains only the `index` circle object (e.g. only the 3rd one).

Answer (score 1):

```
$("shapes:eq(0) circle").eq(index);
```

Answer (score 1):

$('shapes').eq(0).find('circle').eq(index)

Answer (score -1):

```
I think this should work:

$('[name="shapes"]').first().find('circle').eq(index);
```

Comment: `[name="shapes"]` doesn't do the same thing as `getElementsByTagName("shapes")`.